# When I tried to sort a list, I got an error 'dict' object has no attribute

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

My code which created the list is:

```
choices = []
for bet in Bet.objects.all():
    #...
    #Here is code that skip loop if bet.choice exist in choices[]
    #...
    temp = {
        'choice':bet.choice,
        'amount':bet.sum,
        'count':bets.filter(choice=bet.choice).count()}
    choices.append(temp)

choices.sort(key=attrgetter('choice'), reverse=True)
choices.sort(key=attrgetter('amount'), reverse=True)
choices.sort(key=attrgetter('count'), reverse=True)
```

I have to sort by list because model orderby() cant sort by count(),can it?

Comment: Please post (and read) the complete error.

Comment: @skyking: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'choice'`..

Comment: This means that the `dict` object doesn't have an attribute `choice`. Actually reading the error message and thinking a bit about that is a good start when trouble-shooting. It turns out that it's the elements of the list that lacks the attribute.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your dictionaries have no `choice`, `amount` or `count` attributes. Those are *keys*, so you need to use an `itemgetter()` object instead.

```
from operator import itemgetter

choices.sort(key=itemgetter('choice'), reverse=True)
choices.sort(key=itemgetter('amount'), reverse=True)
choices.sort(key=itemhetter('count'), reverse=True)
```

If you want to sort by multiple criteria, just sort once, with the criteria named in order:

```
choices.sort(key=itemgetter('count', 'amount', 'choice'), reverse=True)
```

You probably want to have the *database* do the sorting, however.

Comment: Oh! It's work now. and I have more question
I try this before choices = sorted(choices.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
but it didn't work

Comment: @ZeroOHo: that's because `choices` is a **list** of dictionaries. Lists don't have a `.items()` method.