# How do I sort a JSON value while dumping?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to dump/sort JSON values by a specific time format.

Before asking, I have looked as various questions such as:

1. [When I tried to sort a list, I got an error 'dict' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042961/when-i-tried-to-sort-a-list-i-got-an-error-dict-object-has-no-attribute) (This was actually a problem after trying some things)
2. [Sorting a JSON file by a certain key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266754/sorting-a-json-file-by-a-certain-key) (Most specific one, though I do not use any name keys)
3. [JSON output sorting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774361/json-output-sorting-in-python) (Did not really help)

The structure of my JSON is the following:

```
{
  "Arthur": "12/12",
  "Lisa": "10/12"
}
```

The date format is `dd/mm`. I want to have `10/12` before `12/12` in that matter. This should not however happen while reading out the JSON, but rather while `dumping` the value.

The codes I tried to use:

```py
with open(f"saved_date.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f) # Just so you can see how I read out the JSON


with open('saved_date.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fpp:
    json.dump(data, fpp, indent=2, sort_keys=True) # Sorting the keys does not work obviously

with open('saved_date.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fpp:
    json.dump(sorted(data, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m")), fpp, indent=2) # date is individually given in the format mentioned above
```

Maybe someone here can see what went wrong or give me tips on how to better structure it.
I currently update the JSON with:

```py
        try:
            data[f"{author}"] = date # author is the one using/executing the code
        except:
            new = {author: date}
            data.update(new)
```

Comment: The answer you have accepted will not work with data such as `{'Arthur': '12/12', 'Lisa': '10/12', 'Joe': '31/05'}`

Comment: @Nick is correct, I've incorrectly sorted by day first and then month, when sorting would typically be done with month first then date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = {'Arthur': '12/12', 'Lisa': '10/12'}

with open('saved_date.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])), f, indent=2)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Lisa": "10/12",
  "Arthur": "12/12"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your dates are in `dd/mm` format, you *cannot* sort them alphabetically; you need instead to sort on the `mm` part, then the `dd` part:

```
data = {'Arthur': '12/12', 'Lisa': '10/12', 'Joe': '31/05'}

json.dumps(dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].split('/')[::-1])), indent=2)
```

Output:

```
{
  "Joe": "31/05",
  "Lisa": "10/12",
  "Arthur": "12/12"
}
```